# Ayuda con error de muestra de array en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo que consultar una base de datos MySQL (Versión del servidor: 5.5.55-38.8-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 38.8, Revision 11f5bbd )que lleva los barriles de una cervecería. 
 Los campos son pocos y sencillos: número de barril, lote, ubicación y fecha de último movimiento.
Mi problema es que cuando hago la consulta, **desaparece el primer resultado**, lo cual, por ejemplo para consultar stock, nos da un barril de menos, y cuando se hace una consulta a ver cuántos barriles hay en un cliente, nos da uno de menos y así con todas las consultas.
He aquí mi código. El ejemplo es para consultar todos los barriles de un lote.

```
    <?php
    $result=mysql_query("select * from stock where lote='$lote'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    rsort($row);

    <div class="row" style="background-color:#000">

    <?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>

    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#000">
    <?php echo $row ["barril"];?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#000">
    <?php echo $row['lote'];?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:#000">
    <?php echo $row ["ubicacion"];?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:#000">
    <?php echo $row['cap'];?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:#000">
    <?php echo $row['fechaultimo'];?>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <?php } mysql_free_result($result);?> 
    </div>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema puede venir en que lees el primer registro antes del bucle pero no haces nada con él:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Y luego al iniciar el bucle vuelves a llamar a mysql_fetch_array recuperando el siguiente registro que sí tratas:

```
<?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
```

Yo probaría a quitar la primera línea que te he comentado y la siguiente. Estas dos, vamos:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
rsort($row);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, mi amigo. Lo probaré ahora mismo!

Comment: Y claro que sí! Funcionó perfecto, y era bastante visible el error, pero ya ves, cuando más lo miras menos lo ves. Mil gracias, Javier!

Comment: De nada. ¡Encantado de poder ayudar!